# Unable to install rvm using curl (https protocol issue)

Tags: ruby, curl, rvm

I have a following problem. When using

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

to download rvm, I get error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I'm unsure how to fix it, any thoughts? If you need more information, I'd be more than happy to provide.

@Edit: More information

```
apt-cache policy curl 

curl: Installed: 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4 Candidate: 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4 
Version table: *** 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4 0 500 
http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 
Packages 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 
Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 7.37.1-1ubuntu3 0 
500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

And

```
which curl 

/usr/local/bin/curl
```

Comment: How did you install `curl`? Are `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and `libcurl3-gnutls` installed?

Comment: Are you required to use curl? perhaps you could try `wget -O-` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, curl is a must.
@muru Now that I think about it, it might be because I installed curl7.30 when I've been doing some cpp programming, maybe it's because of this? Other than that curl was already installed on my system. How do I check for libcurl4-gnutls-dev and libcurl3-gnutls?

Comment: Never mind, the default `curl` has SSL support compiled in - those packages are only need for developing (or other applications). Check which curl you are running (`which curl`), and if you have Ubuntu's curl installed (`apt-cache policy curl`).

Comment: @muru 
`apt-cache policy curl
curl:
  Installed: 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.4 0
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.37.1-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages`


And `which curl` out: /usr/local/bin/curl

Answer (score 0):

You have Ubuntu's curl installed, and another curl installed in `/usr/local`. Either specify the full path to get Ubuntu's curl (`/usr/bin/curl`), or change the `PATH` for your script to skip `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I've tried both options, still getting the same error. Going to try to remove curl and install it again.